# Django fails to find static files served by nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I know this is a really noobish question but I can't find any solution despite finding the problem trivial.

I have a django application deployed with gunicorn. The static files are served by the nginx server with the following url : `myserver.com/static/admin/css/base.css`. However, my django application keep looking for the static files at `myserver.com:8001/static/admin/css/base.css` and is obviously failing (404).

I don't know how to fix this. Is it a django or an nginx problem ? Here is my nginx configuration file :

```
server {
    server_name myserver.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/myproject/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

EDIT : 
The django app runs with : `gunicorn_django --bind 127.0.01:8001`

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic` on your server? Also is your static root setup correctly?

Comment: Yes and yes. The nginx files are retrieved and served correctly at `myserver.com/admin/[...]` (I can read them with my web browser). My static root is set to /home/myproject/static.

Comment: Do you connect to gunicorn with a socket? what is your gunicorn startup script? can you paste it?

Comment: It seems like you trying to access your site by 8001 port: myserver.com:8001. Am I right?

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov Yes. No specific reason for this. I've never understood why I had to as it seems that / redirects to 127.0.0.1:8001 anyway. Should I run gunicorn on 127.0.0.1 instead of myserver.com ?

Comment: I'm using the depreciated command : `gunicorn_django --bind myserver.com:8001`

Comment: No, you just have to access your site by default port (80). Your site is accessible by nginx which listen 80 port and proxy your requests to gunicorn and give back static. I don't know exactly how gunicorn works (I prefer uwsgi), but it seems like you access qunicorn directly without nginx.